# spark-submit on AWS EMR Throws Exception

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, pyspark, amazon-emr, spark-submit

I run the following command on the master node of an AWS EMR cluster (**release label: emr-6.1.0, hadoop distribution: Amazon 3.2.1**) -

```
% spark-submit \
--deploy-mode cluster \
--master yarn \
main.py
```

It throws the following exception

```
21/10/01 16:25:47 INFO ApplicationMaster: Waiting for spark context initialization...
21/10/01 16:25:47 WARN SparkConf: The configuration key 'spark.scheduler.listenerbus.eventqueue.size' has been deprecated as of Spark 2.3 and may be removed in the future. Please use the new key 'spark.scheduler.listenerbus.eventqueue.capacity' instead.
21/10/01 16:25:47 ERROR ApplicationMaster: User application exited with status 1
21/10/01 16:25:47 INFO ApplicationMaster: Final app status: FAILED, exitCode: 13, (reason: User application exited with status 1)
21/10/01 16:25:47 ERROR ApplicationMaster: Uncaught exception:
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Exception thrown in awaitResult:
    at org.apache.spark.util.ThreadUtils$.awaitResult(ThreadUtils.scala:302)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster.runDriver(ApplicationMaster.scala:500)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster.run(ApplicationMaster.scala:264)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anon$3.run(ApplicationMaster.scala:890)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anon$3.run(ApplicationMaster.scala:889)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1730)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$.main(ApplicationMaster.scala:889)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster.main(ApplicationMaster.scala)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkUserAppException: User application exited with 1
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.PythonRunner$.main(PythonRunner.scala:111)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.PythonRunner.main(PythonRunner.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anon$2.run(ApplicationMaster.scala:728)
21/10/01 16:25:47 INFO ApplicationMaster: Deleting staging directory hdfs://<ip-address>.ec2.internal:8020/user/root/.sparkStaging/application_<id>_0003
21/10/01 16:25:48 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Shutdown hook called
```

Does anybody know how to fix or debug this?

**EDIT:**
Here is the content of `main.py`. I am only attaching (what I think is) the relevant part of the spark session initialization.

```
from datetime import datetime
import logging
import os
import sys

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf, struct
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType


logger = logging.getLogger('py4j')


def main():
    logger.info('initializing spark')
    spark = (SparkSession
             .builder
             .master('yarn')
             .appName('MySpark')
             .enableHiveSupport()
             .getOrCreate())
    spark_context = spark.sparkContext
    spark_context.setLogLevel('ERROR')
    .
    .
    .

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Can you print the contents of main.py

Comment: @swapnilshashank, sure thing. I updated the original question.

Comment: can you try with emr 6.3.0 version with spark version checked 3.1.1